# Combine DetailView and UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am new to Django and I need to know how to have `DetailView` and `UpdateView` on the same Page.

I have two Models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    CustomerNo   =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Company      =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Str          =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Zip          =  models.IntegerField()
    City         =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Name         =  models.CharField(max_length=200)                                                 
    Phone        =  models.IntegerField()
    Mobile       =  models.IntegerField()
    Email        =  models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    Web          =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Info         =  models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Company

class Contact(models.Model):
    Contact_Company    = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Contact_Name       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Contact_Phone      = models.IntegerField()
    Contact_Mobile     = models.IntegerField()
    Contact_Fax        = models.IntegerField()
    Contact_E_Mail     = models.EmailField()
    Contact_Web        = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Contact_Name
```

I want to build a page where I can see the company data from the first model and an update form for contacts realeted to the first model.

I enter the page with `pk`, from the previous page, its a `DetailView` for the first Model and with additionally context to list the Contact data with a for loop in Template.

I can use `UpdateView` to get data in the form and save it. but I don't know
how do display the realeted Company on the same page. Is there a way to use `DetailView` and `UpdateView` together?

I can use this `UpdateView` to change the Contact data, but I don't know how to include extra context from the first model to display the address on same page.

The success URL is wrong too. 
I need to pass the `pk` from the first model so I can go back to the right list on previous page.

```
class ContactUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = ContactCreateForm
    template_name = 'customer/contact_update.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('customer_list', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Maybe `FormMixin` is a solution, I used it to Display the Data from 
first Model and form for second Model on same Page. But I am really stuck 
to realize this with UpdateForm.

I hope you understand my problem, sorry for my english.

Thank you for your help.

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Company
from .models import Contact
from django.forms import HiddenInput
from django import forms

class CompanyCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'


class ContactCreateForm(ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        widgets = {'Contact_Company': forms.HiddenInput()}

        fields = [

                'Contact_Company',
                'Contact_Name', 
                'Contact_Phone',
                'Contact_Mobile',
                'Contact_Fax',
                'Contact_E_Mail', 
                'Contact_Web',
```

Comment: Have your created Contact Update Form in forms.py? You can add that form in your DetailView using get_context_data. (Or update your question with forms.py and I will add an answer)

Comment: i post my forms.py, i have one ContactCreateForm.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add form in the detail view,

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
      model = Post  #your model name
      template_name = 'detail.html' #your template

      # here you will add your form
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          context['contactupdateform'] = ContactCreateForm()
          return context

      # Add POST method
      def post(self, request, slug):
          post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
          form = contactupdateform(request.POST)

          if form.is_valid():
             # from here you need to change your post request according to your requirement, this is just a demo
             obj  = form.save(commit=False)
             obj.post = post
             obj.author = self.request.user #to add the user
             obj.save()
             return redirect('detail', post.slug) #add your url
```

Make sure you are adding the POST request correctly, according to your model and url. This is an outline you can refer.

To add the form in the HTML, you need to do this,

```
{% for form in contactupdateform %}
     <-- Add Your CSRF token and form here --!>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import this (LoginRequiredMixin) and insert in the updateview as an argument as the contact is a user

then try putting this in the models.py file :
 def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customer_list', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

and remove (get_success_url) from views.py

You might need these too in the updateview Class "ContactUpdate"
login_url = '/login/'
redirect_field_name = <-- template path(html) of the page you want to reverse to...
       HOPE THIS HELPS...